# Which characters are included in the Lua punctuation string pattern (%p)?

Tags: lua, punctuation, lua-patterns

I haven't been able to  find documentation of which characters compound the punctuation set `"%p"` in Lua.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is **locale dependent**, it is a direct interface to the C function.
Actually, if there is a C standard function which does something similar to the Lua function, it is near-certain that the Lua function just wraps the C function, warts and all, even without looking at the specific case.
<sub>(This is part of the reason `file:read()` still has [trouble reading text with embedded zeroes](/questions/23598501/failure-to-read-full-line-including-embedded-zero-bytes) in 5.2, maybe even will have in 5.3)</sub>

While [Amaden](/u/240443) gave [a good answer for the "C" locale](/a/24196194), and [ColonelThirtyTwo](/u/646619) gave [the right way to check for the current locale](/a/24196201), the C standard only says:

> *`ispunct()`*: The `ispunct` function tests for any printing character that is one of a locale-specific set of punctuation characters for which neither `isspace` nor `isalnum` is true. In the "C" locale, `ispunct` returns true for every printing character for which neither `isspace` nor `isalnum` is true.

Answer (score 9):

`%p` is matched by the C function `ispunct` ([C source v 5.2](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lstrlib.c.html#match_class)), which matches the following:

```
041 ‘‘!’’     042 ‘‘ ’’       043 ‘‘#’’       044 ‘‘$’’       045 ‘‘%’’ 
046 ‘‘&’’     047 ‘‘’’’       050 ‘‘(’’       051 ‘‘)’’       052 ‘‘*’’ 
053 ‘‘+’’     054 ‘‘,’’       055 ‘‘-’’       056 ‘‘.’’       057 ‘‘/’’ 
072 ‘‘:’’     073 ‘‘;’’       074 ‘‘<’’       075 ‘‘=’’       076 ‘‘>’’ 
077 ‘‘?’’     100 ‘‘@’’       133 ‘‘[’’       134 ‘‘\’’       135 ‘‘]’’ 
136 ‘‘^’’     137 ‘‘_’’       140 ‘‘‘’’       173 ‘‘{’’       174 ‘‘|’’ 
175 ‘‘}’’     176 ‘‘~’’
```

(From `man ispunct`)

Answer (score 9):

A small script to find them:

```
for i=0,255 do
    if string.match(string.char(i), "%p") then
        io.write(string.char(i))
    end
end
io.write("\n")

-- $ luajit test.lua
-- !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```